# Aggregating an array of objects into an object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this:

```js
[
    {
        "path": [
            "attributes"
            "redirectUri"
        ],
        "message": "must be an absolute URI.",
    },
    {
        "path": [
            "attributes"
            "redirectUri"
        ],
        "message": "blabla",
    },
    {
        "path": [
            "attributes"
            "anotherField"
        ],
        "message": "second",
  }
]
```

I'd like to parse it and produce an object like this:

```
{
  redirectUri: "must be an absolute URI., blabla",
  anotherField: "second"
}
```

1. map and join `message` for the same `path[1]`, separated by comma
2. take into account only `path[1]` as the key

any help would be greatly appreciated.

I did not go very far, I can do this in ruby but not in javascript, for now I'm trying

```
const errorObject = result.data.appCreate.errors
  .map(obj => ({ [obj.path[0]]: obj.message }))
```

but I'm looking at reduce

Comment: So...what have you tried so far ?

Comment: have you tried anything? what does not work?

Comment: I did not go very far, I can do that in ruby but not in javascript, for now I'm trying `const errorObject = result.data.appCreate.errors.map(obj => ({ [obj.path[0]]: obj.message }))` but I'm looking at reduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You iterate through each term using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), this lets us keep a new object with the result. We can also use [`Destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the exact properties that we need.

```js
let arr = [ { path: ['attributes', 'redirectUri'], message: 'must be an absolute URI.', }, { path: ['attributes', 'redirectUri'], message: 'blabla', }, { path: ['attributes', 'anotherField'], message: 'second', }, ];

let res = arr.reduce((acc, { path: [, tag], message }) => {
  acc[tag] = acc[tag] ? acc[tag] + ', ' + message : message;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the many ways to do this is as follows:

```
const input = [
  {
    path: ["attributes", "redirectUri"],
    message: "must be an absolute URI.",
  },
  {
    path: ["attributes", "redirectUri"],
    message: "blabla",
  },
  {
    path: ["attributes", "anotherField"],
    message: "second",
  },
];

const output = input.reduce((prev, next) => {
  const { path = [], message } = next;
  const key = path[1];
  prev[key] = (prev[key] || "") + message;
  return prev;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

#Edit1:

For those who are concerned about the eslint no-param-reassign warning, I would recommend you guys please read the following eslint official GitHub issues:

1. https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/8007
2. https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/8581
3. https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/6339

If you don't wanna disable eslint on that line then one way to fix it would be as follows:

```
const output = input.reduce((prev, next) => {
  const { path = [], message } = next;
  const key = path[1];
  return { ...prev, [key]: (prev[key] || "") + message };
}, {});
```

Comment: thanks, I learned something, any way to not make eslint angry? `Assignment to property of function parameter 'prev'. eslintno-param-reassign`

Comment: It's an eslint exception. Please checkout the following eslint issues which specifically discuss this and its possible solutions:
1. https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/8007
2. https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/8581
3. https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/6339

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over object, check if key `obj[i]['path'][1]` is present in output object or not, if present concatenate otherwise make a key-value pair.

```js
var obj = [
    {
        "path": [
            "attributes",
            "redirectUri"
        ],
        "message": "must be an absolute URI.",
    },
    {
        "path": [
            "attributes",
            "redirectUri"
        ],
        "message": "blabla",
    },
    {
        "path": [
            "attributes",
            "anotherField"
        ],
        "message": "second",
  }
]; 
var output = {}; 
for(let ob of obj){
    if(output[ob['path'][1]] ==undefined) output[ob['path'][1]] = ob['message']
    else output[ob['path'][1]] += `, ${ob['message']}`; 
}
console.log(output);
```